# Change existing sql to left join only on first match

Tags: sql, sql-server

Adding back some original info for historical purposes as I thought simplifying would help but it didn't. We have this stored procedure, in this part it is selecting records from table A (calldetail_reporting_agents) and doing a left join on table B (Intx_Participant). Apparently there are duplicate rows in table B being pulled that we DON'T want. Is there any easy way to change this up to only pick the first match on table B? Or will I need to rewrite the whole thing?

```
SELECT 'Agent Calls' AS CallType,
          CallDate,
          CallTime,
          RemoteNumber,
          DialedNumber,
          RemoteName,
          LocalUserId,
          CallDurationSeconds,
          Answered,
          AnswerSpeed,
          InvalidCall,
          Intx_Participant.Duration
  FROM calldetail_reporting_agents
  LEFT JOIN Intx_Participant ON calldetail_reporting_agents.CallID = Intx_Participant.CallIDKey
  WHERE  DialedNumber IN (  SELECT DialedNumber
                            FROM   #DialedNumbers )
     AND ConnectedDate BETWEEN @LocStartDate AND @LocEndDate
     AND (@LocQueue IS NULL OR AssignedWorkGroup = @LocQueue)
```

Simpler version: how to change below to select only first matching row from table B:

`SELECT columnA, columnB FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON someColumn`

I changed to this per the first answer and all data seems to look exactly as expected now. Thank you to everyone for the quick and attentive help.

```
SELECT 'Agent Calls' AS CallType,
          CallDate,
          CallTime,
          RemoteNumber,
          DialedNumber,
          RemoteName,
          LocalUserId,
          CallDurationSeconds,
          Answered,
          AnswerSpeed,
          InvalidCall,
          Intx_Participant.Duration
  FROM calldetail_reporting_agents
  OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                      *
                      FROM Intx_Participant ip
                      WHERE calldetail_reporting_agents.CallID = ip.CallIDKey 
                      AND calldetail_reporting_agents.RemoteNumber = ip.ConnValue 
                      AND ip.HowEnded = '9' 
                      AND ip.Recorded = '0' 
                      AND ip.Duration > 0 
                      AND ip.Role = '1') Intx_Participant
  WHERE  DialedNumber IN (  SELECT DialedNumber
                            FROM   #DialedNumbers )
     AND ConnectedDate BETWEEN @LocStartDate AND @LocEndDate
     AND (@LocQueue IS NULL OR AssignedWorkGroup = @LocQueue)
```

Comment: Hmm, "`#DialedNumbers`", you're sure it's MySQL not SQL Server?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the tables' `CREATE` statements ans some sample data as `INSERT` statements. Also mention the desired result with that sample data.

Comment: It's sql server mgmt studio on our main server, sorry I just clicked on a suggested tag.

Comment: I can't figure out how to edit my tag from mysql. Will work on the other comment

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is just the (a) client but it strongly indicates SQL Server.

Comment: How would you like me to edit the question? As a very basic example it's: Select columnA, columnB from tableA LEFT JOIN tableB on thisColumn. The where clause is essentially unnecessary for purposes of what I'm doing.

Comment: I simplified it as much as I possibly could.

Comment: Great. Instead of adding more information you killed the little there was. You should probably rollback the changes except for the tag change.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to `OUTER APPLY` a subquery getting only one matching row.

```
...
FROM calldetail_reporting_agents
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                         *
                         FROM intx_Participant ip
                         WHERE ip.callidkey = calldetail_reporting_agents.callid) intx_participant
WHERE ...
```

You should add an `ORDER BY` in the subquery. Otherwise it isn't deterministic which row is taken as the first. Or maybe that's not an issue.

Comment: Your answer is totaly right but, can’t you join with the `select top 1...order by ...` and the join in the `on`? I am not sure if you can use the top/order by sintax in a normal join. If so, would be more standard than `outer apply`. He doesn’t specify the database engine.

Comment: OHHHH MY GOSH IT WORKED! Ok this is what it now looks like I need to verify a bit more but the numbers look perfect now. Thank you so much I can't express my gratitude enough.

Comment: Hang on I'm trying to figure out how to show what I changed it to I'm still learning the controls on stack overflow

Comment: @JaimeDrq: You need to be able to filter in the inner query by a value from the outer query, that's why apply is needed. If you want to keep a left join you could maybe use `row_number()` partitioned by the `ip.callidkey` and wrap another `SELECT` around it only taking the `1`s. But yeah, that's possible too, I guess.

Comment: Wonderful. Sorry it's a fires everywhere kind of day where I am so I'm in major stress mode. But this has helped tremendously.

Comment: Also I have added back in some of my original info Mr Sticky Bit! Just in case you know it could help someone else one day. Going to crawl back into the web hole I came from now :) Let me know if it looks worse or if I can improve any more.